# How can I isolate blocks of data from a file

Tags: perl

I have a file like this

```
a score=-120.0
s Chicken.chr22      947 4 +   4081097 tgag
s Turkey.chrZ   31560312 4 -  81011772 ttct
s Mallard.apl2   2559751 4 - 153042893 TTCG

a score=61344.0
s Chicken.chr22                            951 15 +   4081097 c------tgggtgaagcactg
s Turkey.chrZ                         31560316 15 -  81011772 t------tgggtaaggaactg
s Mallard.apl2                         2559755 15 - 153042893 T------TGGGTTAGAAACTG
s Rock_pigeon.scaffold637               370291 15 +    418352 G------AGGGTCAGTTTCTG
s Common_cuckoo.scaffold569             739303 15 +   1009149 C------TGGGTTGAAAACTG
s Anna_s_hummingbird.scaffold44        3039342 15 -  10500161 C------TGGGTTAAACACTG
s Hoatzin.scaffold186                    66281 15 +    155126 C------TGGATAAAGAACTG
s Emperor_penguin.Scaffold155          7152296 15 -   9595628 C------TGGGTAAAAAATTG
s Adelie_penguin.scaffold207            570235 15 -   3061884 C------TGGGTCAAAAACTG
s Crested_ibis.scaffold108            24271571 15 -  27015053 C------TGAGTAAAAACCTG
s Little_egret.scaffold238              365328 14 +   1015180 -------TGGGTTAAAAACTG
s Peregrine_falcon.scaffold41_1        3239034 14 -   3351735 -------TGGGTTAAAAGCTG
s Budgerigar.megascaffold18            4987476 14 +  17573940 -------TGGATAAAGAACTG
s Golden_collared_manakin.scaffold312  1652783 16 +   1993610 A-----CAGGGTTAGGAACTG
s Downy_woodpecker.scaffold1064           9341 21 -    117330 AGTGAGGTGGATTGTGAACTG
```

Each block of data has a first line which begins with `a` and the other lines begins with `s`. After that a blank line separates the blocks.

Unfortunately each block contains different number of `s` lines.

I want to collect the blocks (in a different file with the same format) which will have the first line (starting with `a`) and the number of `s` lines will be equal to a number that I will pass as a parameter.

I wrote the following script, but it doesn't work. Could someone help me with that?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
#use warnings;

use POSIX;

my $maf     = $ARGV[0];
my $species = $ARGV[1];

#It filters the maf file. takes the blocks with all the species

open my $maf_file, $maf or die "Could not open $maf: $!";
my $count = 0;
my @array;

while (my $mline = <$maf_file>) {

  next if /^\s*#/;    #to avoid some lines with comments

  if ($mline =~ /^a/) {
    push(@array, $mline);
  }

  if ($mline =~ /^s/) {

    until ($mline != ~/\s/) {
      push(@array, $mline);
      $count += 1;
    }

    foreach (@array) {

      if ($count == $species) {
        print "$_\n";
      }
    }

    undef(@array);

  }
```

Comment: Is this the Christmas Dinner selection? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Is there an error message? Does it do anything at all? You are talking about another file... does that file look the same as the sample you gave?

Comment: Also, check out https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::AlignIO::maf. It _might_ be what you are looking for.

Comment: it doesn't do anything. Yes the file is just like the sample

Comment: @simbabque [Looks that way to me](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/MAF_multiple_alignment_format). Well spotted.

Comment: Your program won't compile: it has imbalanced braces `{...}`. Also you must never comment out the `use warnings`; you should fix the bug instead. It isn't clear what you want. In your example data file you have a block with three `s` records and a block with fifteen `s` records. Suppose I enter `10` as the second parameter to your program. Do you expect seven additional lines to be added to the first block? Do you expect five lines to be removed from the second?

Comment: Or do you want all the `s` records redistributed so that there are exactly N per block, with the final block taking whatever is left over? This option seems unlikely.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. There are several blocks in the file with different amount of s lines. I just want to print the blocks which they have s lines as much as the number that I'm giving as a parameter. Again, I'm sorry if my English and my programming experience aren't so good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe that I solved it, based on FMc's help.
Thank you very much!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use POSIX;

my $maf = $ARGV[0];
my $species = $ARGV[1];
my $nline = 0;

if ($species == "" || $species == "0") {
$species = 1;
#print "Forching number of species to 1\n";
}
open (FILE, $maf) or die("foo");

local $/ = "\n\n";

while (<FILE>){
my @lines = split /\n/, <>;
my $arraySize = @lines;
foreach (@lines) {
 if ($arraySize == $species +1 ) {
    print "$_\n";
    $nline = 1;
 }
}
if ($nline == 1) {
    print"\n";
    $nline = 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file organized in blocks, you can often change Perl's input record separator in a way that will allow you to process the file block by block. Here's a general sketch.

```
# You should enable these.
use strict;
use warnings;

# Change the input record separator.
# You typically want to make this change within a subroutine or other narrowly
# scoped location within your program.
local $/ = "\n\n";

while (my $block = <>){
    my @lines = split /\n/, $block;

    # Do stuff with the lines in a block.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really asked a question, so it's hard to be much help. But if you just want to get each of your blocks into a separate element of an array, it's really simple. You just put Perl into "paragraph mode" by setting `$/` to the empty string.

```
open my $maf_file, $maf or die "Could not open $maf: $!";
my @blocks;

{
  local $/ = ''; # always localise changes to Perl's special variables
  @blocks = <$maf_file>;
}
```

Comment: The OP wrote *"I wrote the following script, but it doesn't work. Could someone help me with that?"*. That's a question in my book. Not a great question but nevertheless a question. He also says in the comments *"it doesn't do anything. Yes the file is just like the sample"*. That's enough to be getting on with I think.